# the question of Elasticsearch Painless script

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

for the following code:

```
                  def product =doc['value.keyword'].value;
                  if (Objects.isNull(product)) return false;
                  if (params.mustNumber == 1 && /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/.matcher(product).matches()){
                    return Double.parseDouble(product)>3
                  } else {
                    return false
                  }
```

I can find all floating-point type strings greater than 3, but not integers

result are searchable:

```
"buckets": [
        {
          "key": "10.00",
          "doc_count": 138
        },
        {
          "key": "8.00",
          "doc_count": 126
        },
        {
          "key": "12.00",
          "doc_count": 62
        },
        {
          "key": "5.00",
          "doc_count": 49
        },
        {
          "key": "14.30",
          "doc_count": 42
        },
        {
          "key": "9.50",
          "doc_count": 38
        },
        {
          "key": "12.50",
          "doc_count": 36
        }
```

Can not search but should search results:

```
"value":"6",
"value":"8",
"value":"10",
"value":"20"
```

Please help me!!

Comment: It's probably because of your regular expression which looks for numbers with decimals. Why do you use a regular expression to check for numbers?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your regular expression which looks for numbers with decimals. But there's no need to use a regular expression to check for numbers, a try/catch block would do. Try this:

```
              def product = doc['value.keyword'].value;
              if (Objects.isNull(product)) return false;
              if (params.mustNumber == 1){
                try {
                  return Double.parseDouble(product)>3
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  return false;
                }
              } else {
                return false
              }
```